# JWT expire token on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, token, jwt

I'm trying to set the expiration time to a jwt token like this:

```
class JsonWebToken
  def self.encode(payload)
    payload[:exp] = (2).minutes.from_now.to_i #expire in 2 minutes
    JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    return HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)[0])
  rescue
    nil
  end
end
```

But when I try to access the url the token is always valid. Also if I decode the token I never get the exp key:value on the hash.

Any suggestion

### UPDATE

I'm using the [jwt gem](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt)

This is how I authenticated the user.

```
def authenticate_user
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])
    if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json: payload(user)
    else
      render json: {errors: ['Invalid Username/Password']}, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def payload(user)
    return nil unless user and user.id
    {
      auth_token: JsonWebToken.encode({user_id: user.id}),
      user: {id: user.id, email: user.email}
    }
  end
```

Example using curl:

```
curl -X POST -d email="a@a.com" -d password="changeme" http://localhost:3000/auth_user
```

This curl return:

```
{"auth_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.wPPX7T6WJ5K8ucjZF_l8-9mG7IzabcusLeWw1UOhhTM","user":{"id":1,"email":"a@a.com"}}
```

Then on my rails console:

```
JWT.decode("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.wPPX7T6WJ5K8ucjZF_l8-9mG7IzabcusLeWw1UOhhTM", Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
```

and get:

```
[{"user_id"=>1}, {"typ"=>"JWT", "alg"=>"HS256"}]
```

as you can see the token is always valid, even though I set the expiration on this line:

```
def self.encode(payload)
    payload[:exp] = (2).minutes.from_now.to_i #expire in 2 minutes <<--- This one
    JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end
```

Comment: What JWT gem are you using? And can you share a minimal example of creating the token and then decoding it and the expiration not having an effect? (E.g. you could use the above class.)

Comment: @smarx just updated my question for you. Thanks in advance

Comment: You still haven't shared a minimal example that shows the issue. E.g., somewhere there's code that parses out the `Authorization` header and (presumably?) decodes the JWT and is supposed to reject requests with invalid tokens, but I don't see anything like that in the code you've shared. All I can do is say that the JWT gem doesn't appear to be broken, so the issue in your code lies elsewhere.

Comment: @smarx see my curl example please. Your code works, but I don't understand why my code don't

Comment: My assumption: that's not actually the code you're running to create the token. Try adding some logging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple test that shows the JWT gem is working properly:

```
require 'JWT'

class JsonWebToken
  def self.encode(payload, expiration)
    payload[:exp] = expiration
    JWT.encode(payload, 'SECRET')
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    return JWT.decode(token, 'SECRET')[0]
  rescue
    'FAILED'
  end
end

# expire 2 minutes from now
token = JsonWebToken.encode({ :hello => 'world' }, Time.now.to_i + 120)
puts token # eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIiwiZXhwIjoxNDY4Njg3OTc1fQ.NhIsdEa0Q7Wl5Dx6kyJvSZY6E8ViJ5Kooo7rKr2OBPg
puts JsonWebToken.decode(token) # {"hello"=>"world", "exp"=>1468687975}

# expire 2 minutes ago
token = JsonWebToken.encode({ :hello => 'world' }, Time.now.to_i - 120)
puts token # eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIiwiZXhwIjoxNDY4Njg3NzM1fQ.kDD_WWN3ZTTdFXQvYEgm1CgDaE1mEZxjMvQkQEq4HX8
puts JsonWebToken.decode(token) # FAILED
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I forgot to restart my server, that was my problem.

Comment: As predicted. :-) "My assumption: that's not actually the code you're running to create the token."

Comment: @smarx how can i reset token when user logout?